# Image selected from mobile gallery not filling the imagebutton

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I want any image selected from gallery to fill the imagebutton space. But 
Every image is taking different size.I have done following things after reading other similar answers
: 1.scaleType=centerCrop

2.Padding=nothing

3.adjustViewBounds=enabled

4.I have all the mdpi,hdpi,etc forms of the image button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.awani.simpleblogapp.PostActivity">

<Button
android:id="@+id/submitButton"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:text="Submit"
android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/setImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_light"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/add_btn" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/titleField"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Post Title..."
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/postField"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/titleField"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Post Description"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
/>
```

Please suggest the correction. Thank you. (I am using API 25)
images.

Comment: You are using "wrap_content", so the of the imagebutton will be according with the size of the image you are using for each one

Comment: like @DiogoRosa said since your imagebutton height is wrap_content the button height will change acc to image height, either have images of same height or set imagebutton height to static value like 100dp or whatever

Comment: Maybe i can help you if you say you want 2 or 3 images per screen width, insted of using fixed height and width

Comment: I set up that.but now  some images are not fully visible inside the imageButton....as far as I know , mdpi,hdpi,etc should take care of that,right?

Answer (score 0):

Set a height and a width for your button.Don't use wrap_content, wrap_content.

Comment: Thanks...Being new to android,I got to know about wrap-content.I set up the height and width but now some images are not fully visible inside the imageButton.as far as I know,hdpi,mdpi,etc should take care of that,right?

Answer (score 0):

Set height and width for image button, if you use wrap_content the image button will adjust according to the image but it can make unexpected changes to your layout so first set Height and Width, and then use

android:scaleType="fitXY".